# Can I get the index of an element from inside the element? array

Tags: javascript, arrays, anonymous-function

So say I have an array:

can I have an element that tells it's location by calling it? Assuming it's a function.

`var h = ["0", "1", () => { /* code */ }, "3"];`

Where the anonymous function would self evaluate to `"2"`

Comment: It's an interesting question, might I ask what your use-case is?

Comment: @DavidThomas There is no specific use case, I was simply wondering. I just thought it would be very neat if there was a way to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a Proxy by creating a function and overriding its functionality. We also need to create a proxy on the array. This can be done with a Proxy within a Proxy. One to modify the function and one to modify the array. We can then call it like a normal array function.

```js
// The original function
function TheFunction(idx, arg1) {
  console.log('Index:', idx, '--', 'Argument:', arg1)
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 100000)
}

let h = ["0", "1", TheFunction, "3", TheFunction];

// Create a Proxy on the array
h = new Proxy(h, {
  // Execute when an array item is accessed
  get(target, prop) {
    // Test if the item is a function
    if(typeof target[prop] != 'function') throw new Error('Not a function!')
    // Create a new Proxy on the original function
    return new Proxy(TheFunction, {
      // When the function gets called run this instead of what was actually called
      apply(target, thisArg, arguments) {
        return target(prop, ...arguments)
      }
    })
  }
})

console.log('Result:', h[2]('hello'))
console.log('Result:', h[4]('world'))
```

Otherwise we can't execute it directly. Functions have no idea where they are located in a script, they don't know if they are in the global scope, window, array, object, etc. You need a middle-man or helper, in this case we can use a `forEach` that has a second parameter which is the index of the item. You can then pass that as a parameter like this:

```js
var h = ["0", "1", (idx) => { console.log(idx) }, "3"];

h.forEach((itm, idx) => {
  if(typeof itm == 'function') {
    itm(idx)
  }
})
```

If you have an array with one function you can use `findIndex` to do a similar task. However you still need to pass the index to the function so the function can use it:

```js
var h = ["0", "1", (idx) => { console.log(idx) }, "3"];

let idx = h.findIndex(i => typeof i == 'function')
idx > -1 && h[idx](idx)
```

Another reason this isn't possible is because a function can be referenced, so it can be used in an array, or some other place. As you can see here, we have references to a function, and a function that is called outside of the array. The function that is called had no idea if the call was from the array or outside of the array.

```js
function TheFunction(idx) {
  console.log(idx)
}

var h = ["0", "1", TheFunction, "3", TheFunction, "123", TheFunction];

h.forEach((itm, idx) => {
  if (typeof itm == 'function') {
    itm(idx)
  }
})

TheFunction()
```

Comment: So there's absolutely no way of doing so? may I ask why that is, if you don't mind?

Comment: Nope, not by calling the function directly. But using a loop or other function that can get the index, you can pass it to the function and then the function will know.

Comment: The reason is because the function doesn't know it location in a script.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can loop the array and inside check if the element type is a function:

```
var h = ["0", "1", () => {}, "3"]

for(var i = 0; i < h.length; i++){
    if(typeof h[i] === 'function'){
        console.log(i)
    }
}
```

If yes simply get the index of the element.

Comment: As @Get Off My Lawn said not just by executing it, but by iterating over the array will solve it :)